# Django REST: How do i return SimpleJWT access and refresh tokens as HttpOnly cookies with custom claims?

Tags: django, cookies, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, cookie-httponly

I want to send the `SimpleJWT` `access` and `refresh` tokens through `HttpOnly` cookie. I have customized the claim. I have defined a `post()` method in the `MyObtainTokenPairView(TokenObtainPairView)` in which I am setting the cookie. This is my code:

```
from .models import CustomUser

class MyObtainTokenPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class()
        response = Response()
        tokens = serializer.get_token(CustomUser)
        access = tokens.access
        response.set_cookie('token', access, httponly=True)
        return response
```

It's returning this error:

```
AttributeError: 'RefreshToken' object has no attribute 'access'
```

The serializer:

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        print(type(user))
        token = super().get_token(user)
        token['email'] = user.email
        return token
```

But it's just not working. I think I should not define a `post()` method here like this. I think if I can only return the value of the `get_token()` function in the serializer, I could set it as `HttpOnly` cookie. But, I don't know how to do that.

How do I set the `access` and `refresh` tokens in the `HttpOnly` cookie?

**EDIT:**
I made these changes following **anowlinorbit**'s answer:

I changed my serializer to this:

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        token = self.get_token(self.user)
        token["email"] = self.user.email
        return token
```

Since this token contains the refresh token by default therefore, I decided that returning only this `token` would provide  both `access` and `refresh` token.
If I add anything like `token["access"] = str(token.access_token)` it would just add the access token string inside the refresh token string, which it already contains.

But again in the view, I could not find how to get the refresh token. I could not get it using `serializer.validated_data.get('refresh', None)` since now I am returning the `token` from serializer which contains everything.

I changed my view to this:

```
class MyObtainTokenPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.set_cookie('token', token, httponly=True)
        return response
```

Now it's saying:

```
NameError: name 'token' is not defined
```

What's wrong here? In the view I want to get the `token` returned from serializer, then get the acces token using `token.access_token` and set both `refresh` and `access` as cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leave `.get_token()` alone and instead focus on `.validate()`. In your `MyTokenObtainPairSerializer` I would remove your changes to `.get_token()` and add the following

```py
def validate(self, attrs):
    data = super().validate(attrs)
    refresh = self.get_token(self.user)
    data["refresh"] = str(refresh)   # comment out if you don't want this
    data["access"] = str(refresh.access_token)
    data["email"] = self.user.email

    """ Add extra responses here should you wish
    data["userid"] = self.user.id
    data["my_favourite_bird"] = "Jack Snipe"
    """
    return data
```

It is by using the `.validate()` method with which you can choose which data you wish to return from the serializer object's `validated_data` attribute. **N.B.** I have also included the refresh token in the data which the serializer returns. Having both a refresh and access token is important. If a user doesn't have the refresh token they will have to login again when the access token expires. The refresh token allows them to get a new access token without having to login again.

If for whatever reason you don't want the refresh token, remove it from your `validate()` serializer method and adjust the view accordingly.

In this post method, we validate the serializer and access its validated data.

```py
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # you need to instantiate the serializer with the request data
    serializer = self.serializer(data=request.data)
    # you must call .is_valid() before accessing validated_data
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)  

    # get access and refresh tokens to do what you like with
    access = serializer.validated_data.get("access", None)
    refresh = serializer.validated_data.get("refresh", None)
    email = serializer.validated_data.get("email", None)

    # build your response and set cookie
    if access is not None:
        response = Response({"access": access, "refresh": refresh, "email": email}, status=200)
        response.set_cookie('token', access, httponly=True)
        response.set_cookie('refresh', refresh, httponly=True)
        response.set_cookie('email', email, httponly=True)
        return response

    return Response({"Error": "Something went wrong", status=400)
```

If you didn't want the refresh token, you would remove the line beginning `refresh =`  and remove the line where you add the `refresh` cookie.

Comment: Please seemy edit, I'm stuck in the `view`.

Comment: But there's the `email` left out from the token claim.

Comment: I updated the code with the email. You'll see a pattern: first, define the data in the serializer, fetch the data with serializer.validated_data.get() and then use this fetched data as you like.

Comment: @anowlinorbit, is it possible to send a picture back along with the acces_token + refresh token? I am using DRF + SIMPLE JWT.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyObtainTokenPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

        token = response.data["access"] # NEW LINE

        response.set_cookie('token', token, httponly=True)
        return response
```

You can solve it by setting the token as the "access" from the response data.
Btw, did you find any better solution for this?