# Need to return the User ID along with the access and refresh token while fetching the JWT access token in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

**viewset**

```
class CustomRenderer(JSONRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        status_code = renderer_context['response'].status_code
        response = {
          "status": "success",
          "code": status_code,
          "data": data,
          "message": None,
          "user_id": models.Default_User.objects.all(self.id)
        }

        if not str(status_code).startswith('2'):
            response["status"] = "error"
            response["data"] = None
            try:
                response["message"] = data["detail"]
            except KeyError:
                response["data"] = data

        return super(CustomRenderer, self).render(response, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

**settings**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK= {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASS':'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
                                
     
     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
                 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        ]

}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=7),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=30),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
    'TOKEN_USER_CLASS': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.models.TokenUser',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

I need the user id in the response to be fetched while getting the JWT access token call. Currently I'm not able to fetch the user id along with the responses I coded above.

Is there any way to fetch it or else is there any way to decode the token and take the user id and display while getting the token in the code itself?

Comment: I think this answer can help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66199677/9661008